# javafx.scene.control.TextArea.clear() does not clear the displayed text

Tags: java, javafx

I have a small JavaFX application with a TextArea field to display the result of an action.
Before running a class and displaying the result for the second time, I want to cleanup the the TextArea.
I use TextArea.clear();

But the text is still dispayed and only overwritten at the end of the method with TextArea.insertText(0, text).

eBICSResultText is TextArea

```
public void execute(ActionEvent event) {

       eBICSResultText.clear();
       eBICSResultText.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;");
        String currentBankAccess=CBbankAccess.getValue();
        String currentUser=CBuserId.getValue();
        String currentOT=CBorderType.getValue();
        String transferDirect=myEBICSData.getTransferDirect(currentOT);
        List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
        paramList.add(currentUser);
        paramList.add(currentBankAccess);
        paramList.add(currentOT);
        if (transferDirect.equals("R")) {
            paramList.add(1, "send");
            String fileToSend=sendFile.getText();
            if (fileToSend.equals("")) {
                eBICSResultText.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: firebrick; -fx-highlight-text-fill: firebrick;");
                eBICSResultText.insertText(0, "no file to send specified!");
                return;
            }
            paramList.add(fileToSend);
        } else if (transferDirect.equals("S")) {
            paramList.add(1, "fetch");
        } else {
            logger.error("no EBICS run!");
            return;
        }
        String[] EBICSparams = paramList.toArray(new String[0]);
        EBICSKernel kernel = new EBICSKernel();
        kernel.process(EBICSparams);
        int lastResult=kernel.getLastEBICSResult();
        String lastText=kernel.getLastEBICSReturnText();
        if (lastResult == -1 )
            eBICSResultText.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: firebrick; -fx-highlight-text-fill: firebrick;");
        eBICSResultText.insertText(0, lastText);
   }
```

Comment: You are clearing the text at the beginning of your code and then immediately inserting text again a few lines later (depending on a conditional statement). Where are you expecting the application to wait while the text is empty?

Comment: The mthod 
kernel.process(EBICSparams)
runs at least a couple of seconds so there is time enough to see, if the TextArea is cleared. Even updating the area at the start of the method (for example "Request is running..." has no effect and is not displayed.

Comment: If you are running `kernel.process()` on the main thread and it takes a few seconds, it will block any UI updates. Try wrapping that method call in a new Thread; read up on this article: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

Comment: Does kernel.getLastEBICSReturnText(); return the Original text that you clear?

Comment: Yes, it's the text I want to display AFTER each run, but I want a clear textarea BEFORE each run

Comment: All you have to do is comment out all the code after `TextField.clear()` to see if it's working or not.

Comment: Your problem is most likely due to what @Zephyr said.

Comment: Yes, I think that too. I created a task but it is only run once, even so I hit the button several times.
And I don't understand the difference between Thread and Service. I only want to execute a method each time, I hit a button.

Comment: I feel like you should just be checking if you need to clear it not clear it every time and reset it this is a waste time of also `textArea.setText()` will overwrite what you have in there already(for future reference) and since Im here `textArea.clear()`is working otherwise you would have the same statement repeating in your text area

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd check to make sure that the `TextArea` you are clearing is the right one. I've had times where I've set a reference to a text area twice instead of setting them to different values.

Second, JavaFX events should be run in a `Platform.runLater(event)` call. It's possible the text area is not clearing because you aren't on the JavaFX Thread. If you are already (a button clicked, a listener from a `Node` is called), then disregard this commment.

Second, if you're sure it's the right text area and on the JavaFX Application Thread, try using `textArea.setText(text)`.

Comment: I'm sure, the TextArea is correct, because it's the only one I use.
textArea.setText(text) didn't change the behavior.
Regarding your second guess: I'm not deep enough in Java to know which thread I'm currently in, I don't create threads by my own.

Comment: To put your `clearText()` and `setText()` in the JavaFX Application Thread, do the following:

   `Platform.runLater(() -> {
        textArea.clearText();
        textArea.setText(text);
    });`

Then see if it works

Comment: No, still the field is filled after the first run, is displayed when the second run is executed and only overwritten after the second run is finished

Comment: Why would you think they're running on anything other than the JFX Application thread? Java would throw an error if they had tried updating the UI from any other thread and their question does not indicate an exception at all...

Comment: correct, no exception is thrown. TextArea field just keeps the last text.

Answer (score 0):

So I went and turned you function into a runnable example and it works just fine for me. To get it to work I hard coded your values and commented out the things that gave me errors such as classes I don't have (Easier for me feel free to change that)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main extends Application {

    TextArea eBICSResultText = new TextArea("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        HBox hBox = new HBox();

        Button executeButton = new Button("Execute");
        executeButton.setOnAction(this::execute);

        hBox.getChildren().addAll(eBICSResultText,executeButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hBox);
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void execute(ActionEvent event) {
        eBICSResultText.clear();
        eBICSResultText.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;");
        String currentBankAccess="123";//CBbankAccess.getValue();
        String currentUser="456";//CBuserId.getValue();
        String currentOT="789";//CBorderType.getValue();
        String transferDirect="S";//myEBICSData.getTransferDirect(currentOT);
        List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
        paramList.add(currentUser);
        paramList.add(currentBankAccess);
        paramList.add(currentOT);
        if (transferDirect.equals("R")) {
            paramList.add(1, "send");
            String fileToSend="";//sendFile.getText();
            if (fileToSend.equals("")) {
                eBICSResultText.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: firebrick; -fx-highlight-text-fill: firebrick;");
                eBICSResultText.insertText(0, "no file to send specified!");
                return;
            }
            paramList.add(fileToSend);
        } else if (transferDirect.equals("S")) {
            paramList.add(1, "fetch");
        } else {
//            logger.error("no EBICS run!");
            return;
        }
//        String[] EBICSparams = paramList.toArray(new String[0]);
//        EBICSKernel kernel = new EBICSKernel();
//        kernel.process(EBICSparams);
        int lastResult=1;//kernel.getLastEBICSResult();
        String lastText="look at that";//kernel.getLastEBICSReturnText();
        if (lastResult == -1 )
            eBICSResultText.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: firebrick; -fx-highlight-text-fill: firebrick;");
        eBICSResultText.insertText(0, lastText);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Still not sure what the problem is do you want to see the text clear in between the beginning of the function and the end?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, as Zephyr mentioned, to move the actual processing into a seperate class which inherites javafx.concurrent.Service.
The data exchange with this class has to be implemented with getters, setters and events.

```
    public void execute(ActionEvent event) {     
       logger.entry();
       eBICSResultText.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black; -fx-highlight-text-fill: firebrick;");
       eBICSResultText.clear();
       eBICSResultText.setText("Process EBICS...");
       String currentBankAccess=CBbankAccess.getValue();
       String currentUser=CBuserId.getValue();
       String currentOT=CBorderType.getValue();
       String transferDirect=myEBICSData.getTransferDirect(currentOT);
       List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
       paramList.add(currentUser);
       paramList.add(currentBankAccess);
       paramList.add(currentOT);
       if (transferDirect.equals("R")) {
           paramList.add(1, "send");
           String fileToSend=sendFile.getText();
           if (fileToSend.equals("")) {
               eBICSResultText.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: firebrick; -fx-highlight-text-fill: firebrick;");
               eBICSResultText.setText("no file to send specified!");
               return;
           }
           paramList.add(fileToSend);
       } else if (transferDirect.equals("S")) {
           paramList.add(1, "fetch");
       } else {
           logger.error("no EBICS run!");
       }
       BTexecute.setDisable(true);
       MyEBICSService service = new MyEBICSService();
       service.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

           @Override
           public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
               BTexecute.setDisable(false);
               eBICSResultText.setText("EBICS communcation finished");
               int lastResult=service.getLastEBICSResult();
               String lastText=t.getSource().getValue().toString();
               if (lastResult == -1 ) {
                   eBICSResultText.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: firebrick; -fx-highlight-text-fill: firebrick;");
               }
               eBICSResultText.setText(lastText);
           }
       });
       service.setParams(paramList);
       service.start();
   }

...

class MyEBICSService extends Service<String> {

    /** holds the logger */
    private XLogger logger = XLoggerFactory.getXLogger(MyEBICSService.class.getName());

    List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();

    int lastResult = -1;
    String lastText = "unknown";

       @Override
       protected Task<String> createTask() {
          return new Task<String>() {
             @Override
             protected String call() throws Exception {
               String[] EBICSparams = paramList.toArray(new String[0]);
               EBICSKernel kernel = new EBICSKernel();
               kernel.process(EBICSparams);
               logger.debug("EBICSKernel finished");
               lastResult=kernel.getLastEBICSResult();
               lastText=kernel.getLastEBICSReturnText();
               return lastText;
             }
          };
       }

    public final void setParams(List<String> paramList2) {
        this.paramList=paramList2;
    }
    public Integer getLastEBICSResult() {
        return this.lastResult;
    }
}
```